# Can a SQL Server user defined CLR type be initialized by any type other than String?

Tags: c#, sql-server, clr, sqlclr, user-defined-types

I have created a CLR user defined type as a struct in C# and I would like to be able to initialize this type directly from an `int` in SQL Server. The following example works for the string and null values, but fails for the int, with the message: *Operand type clash: int is incompatible with ExhaustiveInt*.

```sql
CREATE TABLE ExhaustiveTest (
    v ExhaustiveInt not null
);
insert into ExhaustiveTest 
values ('100'), (null), (100);
```

I have tried the following in the struct:

```cs
using System;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Data.SqlTypes;  
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

[Serializable]  
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlUserDefinedType(
    Format.Native,  
    IsByteOrdered = true, 
    IsFixedLength = true,
    Name = "ExhaustiveInt",
    ValidationMethodName = "Validate"
)]  
public struct ExhaustiveInt : INullable {  
    private Int32   the_value;  
    private bool    is_unknown;
  
    public bool IsNull { 
        get {
            return false; 
        }
    }  

    public static ExhaustiveInt Null {  
        get {  
            ExhaustiveInt an_exhaustive_int = new ExhaustiveInt();  
            an_exhaustive_int.is_unknown = true;
            an_exhaustive_int.the_value = 0;
            return an_exhaustive_int;  
        }  
    }  

    public ExhaustiveInt(SqlInt32 int_value) {
        this.the_value = int_value.Value;
        this.is_unknown = int_value.IsNull;

    }
    public static explicit operator ExhaustiveInt(SqlInt32 int_value) {
        return new ExhaustiveInt(int_value);
    }
    
    public static ExhaustiveInt Parse(SqlString string_value) {
        ExhaustiveInt v = new ExhaustiveInt();  
        if(string_value.IsNull) {
            v.is_unknown = true;
            v.the_value = 0;
        }
        else {
            v.is_unknown = false;
            v.the_value = Int32.Parse(string_value.Value);
        }
        return v;
    }

    public override string ToString()  {  
        if (this.is_unknown)  
            return "Unknown";  
        else 
            return this.the_value.ToString(); 
    }  

    private bool Validate()  {  
        return true;  
    }  
  
    [SqlMethod(OnNullCall = false)]  
    public bool IsUnknown()  {  
        return this.is_unknown;  
    }  
}
```

It seems, however, that SQL Server is neglecting both the specific constructor and the operator. Is there a way to make SQL Server understand that there is a way to initialize the struct directly from an `int`?

Answer (score 1):

I re-checked the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-types/creating-user-defined-types-requirements) again and this time noticed two things:

1. the `Parse` method requires an input of `SqlString` (as the purpose is to convert from a string), and
2. overloaded constructors are allowed if the UDT is defined in a class, not a struct:

   > A UDT defined in a class must have a public constructor that takes no arguments. You can optionally create additional overloaded class constructors.

I have tried a few things (using the code you provided in the question) but so far haven't been able to get it working as you desire. I'm not sure that even with overloaded class constructors that this will work as you are wanting it to. I believe the ability to do overloaded constructors is purely for your internal use within CLR code, not being accessed from the external T-SQL context. I believe that UDTs are instantiated internally (perhaps explaining the requirement for the constructor taking no arguments) and hence already exist by the time we get to interact with them, even in a `DECLARE` statement. Meaning, we can call it as follows:

1. ```sql
   DECLARE @Int dbo.ExhaustiveInt = NULL;
   DECLARE @Int dbo.ExhaustiveInt = 5;
   ```

   Both of those call the `Parse` method.
2. ```sql
    DECLARE @Int dbo.ExhaustiveInt = 0x1234567801;
    -- This is usually in the form of passing in another variable
    -- of the same UDT, or setting via: @Var = @Var.Method(val);
   ```

   That deserializes the value via the `Read` method (handled internally when using `Format.Native`, or required when using `Format.UserDefined`).

In both cases, the type already exists in order to call either `Parse` or `Read`.

---

Also, I don't think it's going to use this:

```cs
 public ExhaustiveInt(SqlInt32 int_value) {
        this.the_value = int_value.Value;
        this.is_unknown = int_value.IsNull;

    }
```

If it did, and a `NULL` was passed in, it would error as you are not checking `IsNull`, but `Value` would be a null reference if `int_value.IsNull` was true.

Comment: Thanks, already tried that and the assembly will not load then, with an error stating that it is expecting Parse to be defined differently. I think it is expecting String and String alone, since method overloading also fails.

Comment: @LarsRönnbäck Ok, so I checked the documentation ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-types/creating-user-defined-types-requirements ) again and this time noticed two things: 1) the `Parse` method requires an input of `SqlString` (as the purpose is to convert from a string), and 2) overloaded constructors are allowed if the UDT is defined in a class, not a struct: _A UDT defined in a class must have a public constructor that takes no arguments. You can optionally create additional overloaded class constructors._

Comment: @LarsRönnbäck I did some testing. Please see my updated answer...